Article 'The' when use with the name of an island
According standard English, we do not use 'the' with the name of a single island, for example, 'Tasmania' or 'Bermuda'. We just use 'the' when the name refers to a group of islands or is made up of different parts. Is that right? I wonder why we use 'the' when refer to 'The North Island' or 'The South Island' (of New Zealand)?

Same (non) rules as for rivers, lakes, mountains, etc.  Lake Superior but the Great Salt Lake.  Manhattan Island, the Isle of Man.

Presumably 'the north island' is (or was originally) as much a description as a name.

Wikipedia and Conde Nast Traveller use "The North Island", Britannica and Lonely Planet use "North Island". I don't think it's clear-cut.
